# IIS redirects to domain on any request containing this specific literal string 'null'

Tags: asp.net, iis

So I have a very specific issue. I'm working on IIS 10.0 which has some webservices hosted on it from web apis to old-school ASMX webservices. I have a very specific http request coming from a third-party provider that contains the string 'null' (apostrophes are included).

Anytime they consumed one of my endpoints, or **any** endpoint on the server for that matter, it will always redirect back to the base domain. Regardless of the request method type. As long the 'null' value is passed, whether as form-data or a query parameter

I was able to solve it by passing the string as encoded url (%27null%27%).

Locally it works just fine either way, so I assume this is an issue with IIS or the root web.config file that causes this behavior. Does anyone have an idea on what could cause this type of behavior?

Also for clarification, I'm using .NET Framework 4.6 on IIS 10.0

Comment: IIS itself shouldn't redirect such requests, as it does not go up to your payloads like forms data or query strings. To learn what exactly generates the 30x responses, enable FRT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing Maybe you have some third party modules installed on this machine but FRT will tell.

Comment: You may need to check your security settings in IIS and the web.config file to see if there are some rules that might cause this behavior, an empty string might cause some kind of security validation or filtering to start.

Answer (score 0):

What rewrite rules have you set up for the web in IIS? You need to check if the rewrite rules modify or block incoming requests based on certain conditions. The string "null" may trigger a rewrite rule, resulting in redirection behavior. You can try disabling URL rewrite rules and see if that fixes the problem.

URL Rewrite Module in IIS:[Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)